# Should I use 'one' or 'that' in 'from {one/that} of' and 'to {one/that} of'?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

I am trying to write a sentence in which the character's expression (or tone of voice) turns from surprise to derision. I am trying to write it in this way:

> His tone changed **from one of** surprise **to that of** derision.

Could you tell me if it is correct, or if the *one* must be replaced with *that*? Also show me additional ways to write it.

Comment: Your example is *extremely* "unidiomatic". Primarily because we naturally expect the first ***one*** to be "paralleled" by another. The effect of switching to ***that*** is to imply that the writer wishes to specifically call attention to the fact that there are *many* "tones of surprise", but only *one* "tone of derision". Which is a pretty strange idea to want to assert.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  interesting you say that.  Because of the contrast I would expect not to repeat "one of" and so I find OP's phrasing to be accurate and even elegant.  I'm not saying you're wrong, but I wonder why it sounds pleasing to me even if it is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the more idiomatic way feels to me to be "from **one** of _____ to **one** of _____", with no "that" at all.  It isn't *wrong* to use "that", but it isn't as common.  It feels more natural to this US English speaker that an expression is *one of X* (that is, just *an* expression of X) than that an expression is *that of X* (that is, a *specific* expression of X).

Google Books Search isn't perfect, but it helps us get a feel for how common certain constructions are.  For example, [if we look up "from one of anger to **one** of", we find about 256 results.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22from%20one%20of%20anger%20to%20one%20of%22&*)  But if we look up ["from one of anger to **that** of", we only get about 8 results.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22from%20one%20of%20anger%20to%20that%20of%22&*)  And if we look up ["from that of anger to that of", there are only about 5 results.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22from%20that%20of%20anger%20to%20that%20of%22&*)  A similar patterns holds if you use *surprise* or *joy* or anything else.